# permission questions

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions

I have a file(it is not read only) stored on usb drive, I found that I have no write permission on it since I am not an administrator. After copying it to my local hard drive, I found that I can write to it without any problem.

I want to know why? I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this at home or at work/school? If the latter, they may have locked down usage of USB thumb drives.

If it's at home, it's a permissions issue that can simply be fixed by reformatting the drive to FAT32.

If you can't do that for some reason, you'll have to change permissions to add "Full Control" to your user group, however, this would have to be done by an administrator.

Comment: ... or set 'Full Control' to _Everyone_. You might need to added the _Everyone_ group/user first via the Advance options.